# Silex not firing TERMINATE event

Tags: php, symfony, silex

Trying to build out a controller in Silex to send an email in Swiftmailer.  When the message wasn't getting sent, I did some debugging and found the TERMINATE event isn't actually getting fired.  I can't find a reason why this would happen. I even trimmed down my controller to just return `$app->json([], 200)` and it still won't fire the event.  Any reason a controller would end after sending the response, but not fire the event?

BTW, running PHP7, Ngnix, with PHP-FPM

Comment: How did you debug this? You know terminate is called after the controller, and you see no output (assuming php-fpm), right?

Comment: Monolog didn't log the event for the one route while it did for others.

Comment: There may be an exception there, but should have been logged. Maybe you have a `die` there? Can you use xdebug and go step-by-step after your controller execution?